How to position rounded end borders correctly on a circular graph using only CSS?
I'm trying to create a circular graph using only CSS and HTML, where each segment has a border with rounded ends at both the start and end. However, I'm struggling with positioning the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements to correctly mark the start and end of each segment's border.
Here's what I'm currently working with:

I'm using conic-gradient to fill the circle based on a percentage (--value).
I want to add small rounded borders (12px diameter) at both the start (::before) and end (::after) of the border for each segment.

I'm using calc() along with cos() and sin() to try to calculate the position of the ::after pseudo-element based on the percentage of the circle filled (--value). However, it doesn't seem to be working correctly.
How can I accurately position the ::after pseudo-element at the end of the filled segment on the circular graph, ensuring that it aligns with the edge of the filled arc?
Thank you for your help!
This is a simplified version of my CSS:
.circular {
        &__graph {
        grid-area: b;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 36px;
        justify-content: center;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding-left: 65px;

        &-chart{
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
            height: 500px;
            } 
    }

    &__circles{
        display: flex;
        align-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }

&__dial-circle {
        --size: 320px;
        --thickness: 12px;
        width: var(--size);
        height: var(--size);
        border-radius: 60%;
        background: conic-gradient(var(--color, #1e90ff) calc(var(--value)* 1%), #F9F9F9 0);
        mask: radial-gradient(farthest-side, transparent calc(100% - var(--thickness)), white calc(100% - var(--thickness) + 1px));
        position: absolute;
        //transform: rotate(180deg);


        &::before, &::after {
            content: ' ';
            width: 12px;
            height: 12px;
            position: absolute;
            background: var(--color, #1e90ff);
            left: calc(50% - 7px);
            top: 0;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

        &::after{
            border: 1px solid red;
            --angle: calc(var(--value) * 3.6);
            --radius: calc((var(--size) / 2) - var(--thickness));

            left: calc(50% + var(--radius) * cos(var(--angle) * (pi / 180)) - 6px);
            top: calc(50% + var(--radius) * sin(var(--angle) * (pi / 180)) - 6px);

        }
    }
}

Here's my HTML for this example:
<div class="circular__graph-chart">
    <div class="circular__circles">
        <div class="circular__dial-circle" style="--color: rgb(39, 63, 82);--value: 79.5;--size: 314px;"></div>
        <div class="circular__dial-circle" style="--color: rgb(36, 91, 120);--value: 72.8;--size: 282px"></div>
        <div class="circular__dial-circle" style="--color: rgb(105, 129, 142);--value: 86;--size: 250px"></div>
        <div class="circular__dial-circle" style="--color: rgb(189, 200, 201);--value: 68.2;--size: 217px"></div>
        <div class="circular__dial-circle" style="--color: rgb(231, 195, 184);--value: 79.1;--size: 185px"></div>
        <div class="circular__dial-circle" style="--color: rgb(195, 175, 180);--value: 86.8;--size: 152px"></div>
    </div>
</div>

Here's a live example: https://codepen.io/JonJonCS/pen/BaXopEE
I tried using the cos() and sin() functions in calc() to position the ::after element at the end of the filled segment. I expected the ::after element to appear exactly at the edge of the filled arc, but instead, it's positioned incorrectly and doesn't align with the edge of the segment. I was hoping the red circle would mark the exact end of the border.

Consider using SVG for this stuff. It would be much easier.

With visual debugging, I noticed that all "end caps" were off by 90 degrees. Also, their radius was incorrect.
After adjusting --angle by minus 90 (degrees) and --radius by minus half (instead of all) its thickness in .circular__dial-circle::after, the end cap was properly aligned:


.circular__graph {
  grid-area: b;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 36px;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 65px;
}

.circular__graph-chart {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.circular__circles {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.circular__dial-circle {
  --size: 320px;
  --thickness: 12px;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  border-radius: 60%;
  background: conic-gradient(var(--color, #1e90ff) calc(var(--value)* 1%), #F9F9F9 0);
  mask: radial-gradient(farthest-side, transparent calc(100% - var(--thickness)), white calc(100% - var(--thickness) + 1px));
  position: absolute;
  /*transform: rotate(180deg);*/
}

.circular__dial-circle::before,
.circular__dial-circle::after {
  content: ' ';
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  background: var(--color, #1e90ff);
  left: calc(50% - 7px);
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circular__dial-circle::after {
  /*border: 1px solid red;*/ /* Commented out for now */
  --angle: calc(var(--value) * 3.6 - 90); /* Added: "- 90" */
  --radius: calc((var(--size) / 2) - var(--thickness) / 2); /* Added: The last "/ 2" */

  left: calc(50% + var(--radius) * cos(var(--angle) * (pi / 180)) - 6px);
  top: calc(50% + var(--radius) * sin(var(--angle) * (pi / 180)) - 6px);
}
<div class="circular__graph-chart">
    <div class="circular__circles">
        <div class="circular__dial-circle" style="--color: rgb(39, 63, 82);--value: 79.5;--size: 314px;"></div>
        <div class="circular__dial-circle" style="--color: rgb(36, 91, 120);--value: 72.8;--size: 282px"></div>
        <div class="circular__dial-circle" style="--color: rgb(105, 129, 142);--value: 86;--size: 250px"></div>
        <div class="circular__dial-circle" style="--color: rgb(189, 200, 201);--value: 68.2;--size: 217px"></div>
        <div class="circular__dial-circle" style="--color: rgb(231, 195, 184);--value: 79.1;--size: 185px"></div>
        <div class="circular__dial-circle" style="--color: rgb(195, 175, 180);--value: 86.8;--size: 152px"></div>
    </div>
</div>



Personally, I find using polar coordinates (angle and radius) with rotate() more intuitive:


.circular__graph {
  grid-area: b;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 36px;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 65px;
}

.circular__graph-chart {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.circular__circles {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.circular__dial-circle {
  --size: 320px;
  --thickness: 12px;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  border-radius: 60%;
  background: conic-gradient(var(--color, #1e90ff) calc(var(--value)* 1%), #F9F9F9 0);
  mask: radial-gradient(farthest-side, transparent calc(100% - var(--thickness)), white calc(100% - var(--thickness) + 1px));
  position: absolute;
  /*transform: rotate(180deg);*/
}

.circular__dial-circle::before,
.circular__dial-circle::after {
  content: ' ';
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  background: var(--color, #1e90ff);
  left: calc(50% - 7px);
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circular__dial-circle::after {
  /*border: 1px solid red;*/ /* Commented out for now */
  --angle: calc(var(--value) * 3.6deg); /* Same as your `* 3.6`, but with unit */
  --radius: calc((var(--size) - var(--thickness)) / 2); /* Added: The last "/ 2" */

  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  
  transform:
    translate(-50%, -50%) /* With `left`, `top`: Place centered */
    rotate(var(--angle)) /* Use `--angle` */
    translateY(calc(-1 * var(--radius))); /* Move outwards (along rotation, back to initial) */
}
<div class="circular__graph-chart">
    <div class="circular__circles">
        <div class="circular__dial-circle" style="--color: rgb(39, 63, 82);--value: 79.5;--size: 314px;"></div>
        <div class="circular__dial-circle" style="--color: rgb(36, 91, 120);--value: 72.8;--size: 282px"></div>
        <div class="circular__dial-circle" style="--color: rgb(105, 129, 142);--value: 86;--size: 250px"></div>
        <div class="circular__dial-circle" style="--color: rgb(189, 200, 201);--value: 68.2;--size: 217px"></div>
        <div class="circular__dial-circle" style="--color: rgb(231, 195, 184);--value: 79.1;--size: 185px"></div>
        <div class="circular__dial-circle" style="--color: rgb(195, 175, 180);--value: 86.8;--size: 152px"></div>
    </div>
</div>




Center element and its transform origin (with left, top and translate(-50%, -50%)).
Rotate as desired (angle of polar coordinate).
Offset as desired (radius of polar coordinate).
Reverse rotation (so the final element isn't rotated).

Here, step 4 is redundant because a circle is similar to its rotation.

Graphics such as these are usually easier in SVG. Take a look at Paulie_D's answer.

Perfect! Actually This is the right answer for the problem itself, but I agree with you and @Paulie_D that is easier to do with SVG (I already did it)

Frankly. mere CSS and HTML is underpowered for this.
Use an SVG and leverage pathLength and stroke-linecap: round


svg {
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 10vh auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

svg circle {
  stroke-width: 5;
  fill: transparent;
}

#outer {
  stroke: lightgrey;
  animation: value 5s linear infinite;
  stroke-linecap: round
}

#inner {
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 10;
  animation: value 5s linear infinite;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

@keyframes value {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 100;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 100 100;
  }
}
<svg viewbox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <circle id="outer" cx="60" cy="60" r="50" pathLength="100" />

  <circle id="inner" pathLength="100" cx="60" cy="60" r="30" />
</svg>




Thank you, it was a way easier: https://codepen.io/JonJonCS/pen/MWNamyG
I made all the calculations before so I could plot the SVG as I wanted
